# How to output every day between start day and end day?

Tags: php, date

I'd like to output every day between start day and end day, for example:

```
$start_day = '20150530';
$end_day = '20150602';

//the output should be array('20150530', '20150531', '20150601', '20150602');
print_r(output_days($start_day, $end_day));

function output_days($start_day, $end_day) {
    // any idea?
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do people write it so complicated?

```
 $start = mktime(0,0,0,9,10,2000);
 $end   = mktime(0,0,0,9,15,2000);
 while($start<=$end)
 {
   $output[]=date("Ymd",$start);
   $start+=86400;
 }
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/371614)**

Comment: Awesome, this should be the best answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$date_from = strtotime("10 September 2000");
$date_to = strtotime("15 September 2000");


$day_passed = ($date_to - $date_from); //seconds
$day_passed = ($day_passed/86400); //days

$counter = 1;
$day_to_display = $date_from;
while($counter < $day_passed){
    $day_to_display += 86400;
    echo $day_to_display;
    $counter++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$start_day = '20150530';
$end_day = '20150602';`

`//the output should be array('20150530', '20150531', '20150601', '20150602');`
`print_r(output_days($start_day, $end_day));`

`function output_days($start_day, $end_day) {
   $strtotime_start=strtotime($start_day);
   $strtotime_end=strtotime($end_day);
   $totaldays=$strtotime_end-$strtotime_start;
   $x=0
   $dates[0]=date('Ymd',$strtotime_star)
  while($x<$totaldays){
     $dates[]=date('Ymd', $strtotime_start+86400);
     $x++;
  }
  $dates[]=date('Ymd',$strtotime_end);
  return $dates;
}`

Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want maybe?

```
function alldays($start_date,$end_date,$format_date="Y-m-d") {

    $seconds = strtotime($end_date) - strtotime($start_date);
    for ($i=0; $i < $seconds ; $i+=(60*60*24)) { 
        $dates[] = date($format_date, strtotime($start_date)+$i);
    }
    return $dates;
}
//Tiny test
print_r(alldays('1999-01-01','1999-02-01'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_day = '20150530';
$end_day = '20150602';

function output_days($start_day, $end_day) {
    while (strtotime($start_day) <= strtotime($end_day)) {
        $date[] = $start_day;
        $start_day = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start_day)));
    }
    return !empty($date) ? $date : 'LOL :) Correct date please';
}

print_r(output_days($start_day,$end_day));
```